# Python OpenCV cap.read() unpacks compressed frames?

Tags: python, opencv, compression, mp4

Hello Stack community,

I'm reading frames from an IP-camera stream and storing them in a list to later on create a video file.
I'm using the python OpenCV library and it works well but ..
The frames that are sent from the IP camera should have a h264 compression but when i check the size of the frames they are 25 MB for a 4K stream. I run out of memory quickly. 
This is **not** the code, but similar to it:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
list = []

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
        list.append(frame)

cap.release()

out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', -1, 20.0, (640,480))
for frm in list:
    out.write(frm)
out.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It seems like `ret, frame = cap.read()` unpacks the frame ?
This generates extra processing each loop and is uneccessary for my intentions with the script, is there a way to retrieve frames without unpacking them ?

Sorry in advance for my probable ignorance.

Comment: maybe you should other tools to get stream and save it directly to file - without using Python - ie. `ffmpeg`, `vlc` - [Capture RTSP stream from IP Camera and store](https://superuser.com/questions/766437/capture-rtsp-stream-from-ip-camera-and-store)

Comment: Python is essential for my purposes ;/

Comment: use other tools to get all images and later use Python to work with this local video. If you learn how to use `ffmpeg`, `vlc` then you can use `Python` use  `ffmpeg`, `vlc` - ie. [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python), [python-vlc](https://wiki.videolan.org/PythonBinding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a test sample for reading h264 stream into memory using [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python).

The sample reads the data from a file (I don't have a camera for testing it).
I also tested the code reading from RTSP stream.

Here is the code (please read the comments):

```
import ffmpeg
import threading
import io

in_filename = 'test_vid.264' # Input file for testing (".264" or ".h264" is a convention for elementary h264 video stream file)

## Build synthetic video, for testing:
################################################
# ffmpeg -y -r 10 -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -t 50 test_vid.264

width, height = 192, 108

(
    ffmpeg
    .input('testsrc=size={}x{}:rate=1'.format(width, height), f='lavfi')
    .output(in_filename, vcodec='libx264', crf=23, t=50)
    .overwrite_output()
    .run()
)
################################################


# Use ffprobe to get video frames resolution
###############################################
# p = ffmpeg.probe(in_filename, select_streams='v');
# width = p['streams'][0]['width']
# height = p['streams'][0]['height']
###############################################


# Stream the video as array of bytes (simulate the stream from the camera for testing)
###############################################
## https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/examples/README.md
#sreaming_process = (
#    ffmpeg
#    .input(in_filename)
#    .video # Video only (no audio).
#    .output('pipe:', format='h264')
#    .run_async(pipe_stdout=True) # Run asynchronous, and stream to stdout
#)
###############################################


# Read from stdout in chunks of 16K bytes
def reader():
    chunk_len_in_byte = 16384  # I don't know what is the optimal chunk size
    in_bytes = chunk_len_in_byte

    # Read until number of bytes read are less than chunk_len_in_byte
    # Also stop after 10000 chucks (just for testing)
    chunks_counter = 0
    while (chunks_counter < 10000):
        in_bytes = process.stdout.read(chunk_len_in_byte) # Read 16KBytes from PIPE.
        stream.write(in_bytes) # Write data to In-memory bytes streams
        chunks_counter += 1
        if len(in_bytes) < chunk_len_in_byte:
            break


# Use public RTSP Streaming for testing
# in_stream = "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"

# Execute ffmpeg as asynchronous sub-process.
# The input is in_filename, and the output is a PIPE.
# Note: you should replace the input from file to camera (I might forgot an argument that tells ffmpeg to expect h264 input stream).
process = (
    ffmpeg
    .input(in_filename) #.input(in_stream)
    .video
    .output('pipe:', format='h264')
    .run_async(pipe_stdin=True, pipe_stdout=True)
)

# Open In-memory bytes streams
stream = io.BytesIO()

thread = threading.Thread(target=reader)
thread.start()

# Join thread, and wait for processes to end.
thread.join()

try:
    process.wait(timeout=5)
except sp.TimeoutExpired:
    process.kill()  # Kill subprocess in case of a timeout (there might be a timeout because input stream still lives).

#sreaming_process.wait()  # sreaming_process is used 

stream.seek(0) #Seek to beginning of stream.

# Write result to "in_vid.264" file for testing (the file is playable).
with open("in_vid.264", "wb") as f:
    f.write(stream.getvalue())
```

In case you find it useful, I may add some more background descriptions before the code.

Please let me know if the code is working with a camera, and what you had to modify.

Comment: Thanks alot for your input, I’ll try to see how this could be  implemented into my script. In order to understand more, how does it differ from the openCV approach I’m currently using? I see ffmpeg seems to be what people are recommending.

Comment: OpenCV decodes each frame into (usually) BGR format. Each decoded frame is 3840*2160*3 bytes for 4K stream (for storing it you need to encode [compress] it]. With FFmpeg, you have the option to grab the encoded (compressed) h264 stream that can be about 100 to 1000 times smaller by average. You may store the encoded video stream (in disk or RAM), and decode it later (decode it "frame by frame", only when you need the decoded frames - when displaying the video for example).

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed. Much appreciated !